# LINQ Basics, How do I do a groupby and get a string at the end?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hello I have a class like so

```
class myclass
{
    public string string1;
    public string string2;
    public string string3;
}
```

And I have a list of them and I want to produce a list of strings of unique string1 s.

```
List<myclass> myInstance = GetInstanceOfMyClass();

MethodThatRequiresListOfStrings( myInstance.GroupBy(p => ??????? .ToList<string>());
```

What would replace the ??????? ?

I can't believe I've gone this long without doing a group by with a lambda expression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would not use a grouping at all. If you just want *distinct* string1 values, use `Distinct()`.

```
myInstance.Select(obj => obj.string1).Distinct(); // .ToList()
```

If you want to learn how to group, consider this

```
myInstance.GroupBy(obj => obj.string1).Select(grp => grp.Key); // .ToList()
```

However, again, I would go with the first option.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to produce a list of strings of
>   unique string1 s.

In that case, you don't need a grouping operation; you probably want to use the [**`Distinct`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) operator:

```
var distinctString1s = myInstance.Select(p => p.string1)
                                 .Distinct()
                                 .ToList();

MethodThatRequiresListOfStrings(distinctString1s);
```

In other words, construct a new sequence by *projecting* each `myclass` instance to its `string1` field, and then load the distict items of *that* sequence into a list.

Answer (score 0):

No GroupBy needed:

```
var distinctString1s = myInstance.Select(x => x.string1)
                                 .Distinct()
                                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MethodThatRequiresListOfStrings(myInstance.Select(s=>s.string1).Distinct().ToList());
```